# Nested routing in webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am trying to create a URL routing that goes like:

/view/*database*/*table*

Where *database* and *table* is parameterized

that maps to a handler like

```
class ViewTable:
    def get(self, database, table):
        #get table schema
```

I was wondering how I can route this?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/view/(.*)/(.*)', ViewTable), ], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the regex you are using to set up the routing (they are greedy, so the `/` matches `.*`. A better way to set it up would be:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    (r'/view/<database:[^/]*>/<table:[^/]*>', ViewTable),
], debug=True)
```

Even better, though, would be to use a regular expression that captures exactly the characters that what your database and table names can capture.